# Trouble while extending CKAN template

Tags: jinja2, ckan, theming

I was extending a `ckan` template as per:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/templates.html
So when I add `{% ckan_extends %}` in an empty `index.html` file in my extension to use the original index.html I get the following exception and traceback(My debug is set to true):

```
WebError Traceback:
⇝ ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
View as:   Interactive (full)  |  Text (full)  |  XML (full)
Module ckan.controllers.home:88 in index          view
>>  return base.render('home/index.html', cache_force=True)
Module ckan.lib.base:174 in render          view
>>  return cached_template(template_name, render_template)
Module pylons.templating:249 in cached_template          view
>>  return render_func()
Module ckan.lib.base:128 in render_template          view
>>  return render_jinja2(template_name, globs)
Module ckan.lib.base:85 in render_jinja2          view
>>  return template.render(**extra_vars)
Module jinja2.environment:989 in render          view
>>  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
Module jinja2.environment:748 in handle_exception          view
>>  traceback = _make_traceback(exc_info, source_hint)
Module jinja2.debug:140 in make_traceback          view
>>  return translate_exception(exc_info, initial_skip)
Module jinja2.debug:182 in translate_exception          view
>>  lineno = template.get_corresponding_lineno(tb.tb_lineno)
Module jinja2.environment:1056 in get_corresponding_lineno          view
>>  for template_line, code_line in reversed(self.debug_info):
Module jinja2.environment:1072 in debug_info          view
>>  self._debug_info.split('&')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Help needed.